# Custom errors being set to off is not being respected in my web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, web-config

I have an ASP.NET app with the `customErrors` flag set to `Off` in web.config; however even with this set, I still get the generic error page as if I had it `On`. Why is this? Why can't I see the errors?

Here is what I see:

[image: generic error page]

And here is my (slightly redacted) web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
   ...
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation />
    <pages enableEventValidation="false">
      <namespaces>
        <!-- TODO: add additional default includes here -->
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="7200" />
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="..." timeout="240" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Admin/default.aspx" timeout="720" requireSSL="true" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <location path="Admin/Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Admin/LoginLost.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="crossdomain.xml">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="robots.txt">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="TermsOfUse.html">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="default.aspx" />
        <add value="Default.htm" />
        <add value="index.htm" />
        <add value="Default.asp" />
        <add value="index.html" />
        <add value="iisstart.htm" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="">
        <network host="" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  <location path="Admin/AdditionalField/AdditionalFieldDialogUpdate.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Admin/AdditionalField/AdditionalFieldSetup.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Admin/SystemReports/XML/XMLReportTagEdit.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Admin/UserMenuReplaceString.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 78D4CC6E-5DE4-4523-8EBC-FCAAE5C310D5-->
```

Comment: Is this running on a server or locally? The file contents you've shown us - are you sure that's what's in the web.config where the application is actually running? No config transforms happening on a CI/CD server that might be changing the web.config on you during deployment?

Comment: This is on a server. There are two instances of this app on the server, it's possible I was looking at the wrong one. I'll check on that in a bit. We don't have CI set up to my knowledge, though it's definitely something we'd like to move towards.

Comment: How are you deploying the application then?

Comment: We have a rather complicated process that involves a PowerShell build script, copying files to the server, and executing SQL DDL scripts, among other things.

Comment: Okay - so is it possible that your PowerShell build scripts are applying the config transforms? When you show us this file in your question, did you copy/paste that from the source code, or from the file on the web server?

Comment: Oh, yes, the script does modify the config files, come to think of it. I know it changes the connection strings; not sure what else it changes. I want to say I got the file in question from the web server?

Comment: Did you look at the config transform files? Are they configured to modify the config file and change the error settings? And how come you don't know where you got this file from? Go look!